# Is there a way to set background-opacity when background is already set?

Tags: css, opacity

I want to set background-opacity only when the background is already set. I'm using `less`, and something I want to do is like this:

```
{
    background: @someColorVar;
    background-opacity: 0.2;
}
```

where say, @someColorVar is set to #0096be.

which does exactly same with

```
{
    background: rgba(0, 150, 190, 0.2);
}
```

since I don't want to find the inherited color hex(#0096be) from the project, and convert it to rgba code(0, 150, 190), and put opacity on it.

It's really annoying...
Just want to set the background-opacity on inherited color.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a pseudo-element as a background layer where you apply the background and the opacity:

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #0096be;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
some text
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use opacity in place of background-opacity.

```css
{
    background-color: #0096be;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna work since opacity also makes elements inside of that DOM too while what I want to do is to set only background opacity only...

Comment: I said in place of background-opacity you have to use opacity because there is no one background-opacity property in CSS.

Comment: I know CSS, what you suggested doesn't have to do with what I am finding.